# .NET Portability Warning: CA1901 PInvoke Declarations Should Be Portable

Tags: .net, pinvoke, code-analysis, portable-applications

When I add the following lines into my code

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void keybd_event(byte key, byte scan, int flags, int extraInfo);
```

and run a code analysis against *Microsoft Basic Correctness Rules*, I get a CA1901 warning. 
Basically, it complains the 4th parameter **int** *extraInfo* works fine on a 32-bit platform but a 64-bit integer type is expected on 64-bit platform.

When I modified the code into **long** *extraInfo*, the 64-bit platform requirement is met but the 32-bit platform is expecting a 32-bit integer.

How to solve this dilemma without suppressing the warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using an [IntPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx) which is a platform-specific type that is used to represent a pointer or a handle:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void keybd_event(byte key, byte scan, int flags, IntPtr extraInfo);
```